# HTML Forms Problem - Adds a line after it ends

Tags: html, forms, formatting

```
<td>
    <form name="search_form" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search_text">          
    <input type="submit" name="search_bt" value="Go">
    </form>
</td>
```

now when ever we use this code it adds an extra line after it ends.... see the image below
[image] see the red boxed area... there is nothing there... nothing but that space is added for no reason by the **FORM**

BUT... BUT.. if i use the code like this

```
<form name="search_form" action="" method="POST">
<td>

    <input type="text" name="search_text">          
    <input type="submit" name="search_bt" value="Go">

</td>
</form>
```

everything is fine... the space disappears..

**WHY SIRE !!!! WHYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thats just the way most browsers treat the form element

use css padding/spacing to tell it that it shouldnt added extra space for form elements.

Answer (score 1):

in your css file just add

```
form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This page has a good write-up on what's occurring.

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/extraspace.html

> Browsers typically leave some empty
>   space, roughly corresponding to one
>   empty line, after a form. The problem
>   discussed here is often classified as
>   “extra vertical space after a submit
>   button”, but this is not the correct
>   diagnosis. Rather, it’s about spacing
>   below the entire form, but it is
>   observed especially often when a form
>   contains just an input button (often
>   inside a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, form elements have CSS styling attached to them. Margins, padding, etc. That's why.

Comment: Its normal - user agents (that's browsers to you folks who don't read the specs) have their own stylesheets which they apply globally unless overridden, so that pages without CSS would look slightly more presentable.